# Swift: Retrieving UserDefaults dictionary data into labels

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am new to swift programming. I am saving some text field data into a dictionary as UserDefaults. I need to retrieve these data back and display it in the following format.

x pounds= x ounds =x grams

This the code where I have saved it into UserDefaults in a dictionary.

```
 var weightDict = [String:Any]()
  var weightArray =  [Any]()

@IBAction func saveWeight(_ sender: Any) {


         weightDict = [:]
         weightDict.updateValue(textOunce.text, forKey: "ounce")
         weightDict.updateValue(textPound.text, forKey: "pound")
         weightDict.updateValue(textGram.text, forKey: "gram")
       weightArray.append(weightDict)


        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

         defaults.set(weightArray,forKey: "savedWeightConversion")

        if let savedWeights = defaults.object(forKey: "savedWeightConversion"){
            weightArray = (savedWeights as! NSArray) as! [Any]
            print("value is",weightArray)
        }

    }
```

To view it on application load

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let savedWeights = defaults.object(forKey: "savedWeightConversion") as? [String] ?? [String]()


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let savedWeights = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedWeightConversion") as? [Any] {
        for i in 0 ..< savedWeights.count{
            if let weightDict  = savedWeights[i] as? [String:Any] {
                print("\(weightDict["pound"] as! String) pounds= \(weightDict["ounce"] as! String) ounds =\(weightDict["gram"] as! String) grams")
            }
        }
    }
}



@IBAction func saveWeight(_ sender: Any) {

    if let savedWeights = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedWeightConversion") as? [Any] {
        weightArray = savedWeights
    }
    weightDict = [:]
    weightDict.updateValue(textOunce.text, forKey: "ounce")
    weightDict.updateValue(textPound.text, forKey: "pound")
    weightDict.updateValue(textGram.text, forKey: "gram")
    weightArray.append(weightDict)


    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.set(weightArray,forKey: "savedWeightConversion")

    if let savedWeights = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedWeightConversion") as? [Any] {
        for i in 0 ..< savedWeights.count{
            if let weightDict  = savedWeights[i] as? [String:Any] {
                print("\(weightDict["pound"] as! String) pounds= \(weightDict["ounce"] as! String) ounds =\(weightDict["gram"] as! String) grams")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This works. But it overrides the previous values and replaces with new values. How can it be done by keeping the previous values as well

Comment: I will be entering the values multiple times and save it.So according to this code every time I enter values It overrides the old values and saves the new one.I want to display the old values as well. And new values should be displayed after the old values that were saved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
  if let savedWeights = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedWeightConversion") as? [Any] {

        if let dic  = savedWeights[0] as? [String:Any] {

            if let ounce  = dic["ounce"] as? String {

               self.ounceLb.text = ounce

            }

            if let pound  = dic["pound"] as? String {

                self.poundLb.text = pound

            }

            if let gram  = dic["gram"] as? String {

                self.gramLb.text = gram

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: How do I load it back when the app loads into labels in the viewDidAppear method